# I'm trying to generage report from excel via python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This the excel:
[image]

I'm try to find out if the task reached to `Last_Queue=='NL_AMS_NSO_TA_TRANSPORT'` and worked by TAC_NL_Member, in the excel if task were taken by TAC_NL_Member member column value is `true`.
I wrote following code to find out but it's not giving me the correct print.

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/611777575/desktop/Python/FY19-20 Classic Stats.xlsx', sheet_name="20-Feb",dtype={ 'TAC NL Member': str})



filt2 = df1.loc[(df1['Last Queue'] == 'NL_AMS_NSO_TA_TRANSPORT') & (df1['TAC NL Member'] == 'TRUE')]


print(filt2)
```

I'm thinking the code is not able to run because of the word TRUE.
Please suggest

Comment: You need to provide the output as well, either error or whatever the output is.

Comment: It's only prininging headers of the excel

Comment: Well this should not be that hard a problem, is there anyway you can share the excel sheet? I mean not the actual data and values, but after changing the names and everything? Maybe in dropbox or google drive. Because it's hard to understand what are the datatypes of your column values, firstly and secondly some columns you are using like Last Queue, I can't see it anywhere in the excel sheet image you just shared. So can you share the sheet? Or maybe output of print(df1.columns) and print(df.dtypes)

Comment: Another small suggestion, if you actually need to perform filtering only, you don't need to give .loc here. You just have to give:
filt2 = df1[(df1['Last Queue'] == 'NL_AMS_NSO_TA_TRANSPORT') & (df1['TAC NL Member'] == 'TRUE')]

I guess that's all your mistake is. Try it

Answer (score 0):

True is a python keyword. 'True' is a string. try removing the quotes.

Comment: no luck , after removing quotes it says that name 'TRUE' is not defined

Comment: it must be True. only T is uppercase.

Comment: I tryied that as well but no luck, python is not showing filterd data

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in using the `.loc` method. Usually it is used to access a whole column, a row or a single element of the DataFrame, as :

```
my_df.loc[my_row, my_col]
```

try :

```
df1[(df1['Last Queue'] == 'NL_AMS_NSO_TA_TRANSPORT') & (df1['TAC NL Member'] == 'TRUE')]
```

you can check both conditions separately to identify the issue:

```
cond_1 = df1['Last Queue'] == 'NL_AMS_NSO_TA_TRANSPORT'
print(df1[cond1]])

cond_2 = df1['TAC NL Member'] == 'TRUE'
print(df1[cond2]])
```

EDIT:

I ran this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Person": ["Person_1", "Person_2"], "TAC NL MEMBER":["TRUE", "TRUE"]})

df[df["TAC NL MEMBER"] == "TRUE"]
```

output:

```
    Person TAC NL MEMBER
0  Person_1          TRUE
1  Person_2          TRUE
```

Comment: Both the ways it's onlt filtering first row.

Comment: Only cond_1 = df1['Last Queue'] == 'NL_AMS_NSO_TA_TRANSPORT'
print(df1[cond_1])  is working , I guess wors TRUE is creating problem, Do you have idea how to deal with word TRUE .